# JQuery dropdownpanel function

Tags: jquery

I have created af dropdownpanel function for a data table, but the function only works on the first button. The panel is shown by adding and removing the class: "visible". Can anyone figure it out? Here is my code:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    $("li.mix #target").click(function() {
     if ($(this).parent().find(".dates").hasClass('visible')) {
            $(this).parent().find(".dates").removeClass("visible");
        } else {
            $(this).parent().find(".dates").addClass("visible");
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<ul id="MixItUpAB2781">
    <li class="mix Januar 2015 date" style="display: inline-block;">
        <span>Januar 2015</span>
    </li>
    <li class="mix color-1 Januar 2015" style="display: inline-block;">
        <span id="target">book pil</span>
        <header class="travel_header">
            <div class="travel_img"></div>
            <div class="info_text">
                <p>
                    1 - 3 måneders adventure
                </p>
                <p>
                    Udrejse dato: 01/01/2015
                </p>
            </div>
        </header>
        <div class="dates">
            <div>
                <table width="100%">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                Varighed
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                Afrejse
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                Hjemrejse
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                Pris
                            </td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <!-- Prøv her -->
                        <tr>
                            <td width="50%">
                                7 uger<br>
                                19 dages overland safari, samt 4 ugers frivilligt arbejde på Noahs Ark i Namibia
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <p>
                                    30. januar 2015
                                </p>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <p>
                                    19. marts 2015
                                </p>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                25.600 kr.
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <a class="btn_boo" href="http://mikkellindblom.dk/client/ah/booking/?ref=1866">book</a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td width="50%">
                                7 uger<br>
                                19 dages overland safari, samt 4 ugers frivilligt arbejde på løveprojektet i Botswana
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <p>
                                    30. januar 2015
                                </p>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <p>
                                    20. marts 2015
                                </p>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                26.700 kr.
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <a class="btn_boo" href="http://mikkellindblom.dk/client/ah/booking/?ref=1867">book</a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="combine"></div>
    </li><!-- FOREACH DESTINATION -->
    <li class="mix Februar 2015 date" style="display: inline-block;">
        <span>Februar 2015</span>
    </li>
    <li class="mix color-1 Februar 2015" style="display: inline-block;">
        <span id="target">book pil</span>
        <header class="travel_header">
            <div class="travel_img"></div>
            <div class="info_text">
                <p>
                    1 - 3 måneders adventure
                </p>
                <p>
                    Udrejse dato: 01/01/2015
                </p>
            </div>
        </header>
        <div class="dates">
            <div>
                <table width="100%">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                Varighed
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                Afrejse
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                Hjemrejse
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                Pris
                            </td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <!-- Prøv her -->
                        <tr>
                            <td width="50%">
                                1 måned<br>
                                2 ugers adventure i Dar es Salaam området og 2 ugers frivilligt arbejde
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <p>
                                    02. februar 2015
                                </p>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <p>
                                    01. marts 2015
                                </p>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                17.300 kr.
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <a class="btn_boo" href="http://mikkellindblom.dk/client/ah/booking/?ref=1868">book</a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td width="50%">
                                2 måneder<br>
                                3 ugers adventure i Dar es Salaam området inklusiv 10 dage på Zanzibar og 5 ugers frivilligt arbejde i Dar es Salaam
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <p>
                                    02. februar 2015
                                </p>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <p>
                                    29. marts 2015
                                </p>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                23.500 kr.
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <a class="btn_boo" href="http://mikkellindblom.dk/client/ah/booking/?ref=1869">book</a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="combine"></div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)... no need for if statement then

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    $("li.mix #target").click(function() {

            $(this).parent().find(".dates").toggleClass("visible");

    });
});
```

Comment: toggles are great, aren't they :D